# How to host a website on personal computer

Tags: networking, dns, webserver, bind

I want to start hosting my website at my own computer as well websites of my friends too (say mini hosting platform).
I learned Debian, Bind9 and Apache for this purpose.

On my system everything is going well.
Even my IP opens up my website from outside my network.
But my domain (say, `abx.com`) does not show my website.

How can I set things up so that `abx.com` points to my website?

Comment: Cross posting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330844/how-to-host-a-website-on-personal-computer-using-debian-bind-and-apache

Comment: Also cross posted http://superuser.com/questions/630254 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160237 http://serverfault.com/questions/530037

Comment: extra cross postings have been deleted or flagged for deletion as i was not aware of cross posting rule.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain's DNS (A record) has to point to your hosting IP. In your local environment this may look as though it is working, but externally it may not. This is due to the nature of DNS, which is hierarchical. Given your example of abx.com, if I were to request that domain the resolver (the system that does the work of converting abx.com to a network IP nn.nn.nn.nn), the following takes place.

The resolver looks at your settings as to where to look for DNS. On windows this setting is in your network properties, and is usually retrieved from DHCP. On unix systems this is fetched from a combination of `nsswitch.conf` and if that contains a `dns` setting for the `hosts` entry, `/etc/resolv.conf` will be used to to look for `nameserver` statements.
Given that `nsswitch.conf` is correct, and `resolv.conf` contains nameserver entries, it will then talk to the nameservers in the order they are listed in the file.

The nameservers, if configured with a cache, will check if they have stored a local entry for the request and if they have, return that result. If they do not have an entry they then do the work of searching this hierarchy of DNS.

In the example of `abx.com.` there are actually three parts to this domain, `.`, `com` and `abx`. The `.` is known as the root node and most DNS will not show it, however it fundamental to how DNS works. (Try doing a `host` or `nslookup` on `www.google.co.uk.` (note the trailing dot) and note that is resolves just as well as `www.google.co.uk`. The same goes for putting the dot at the end of an address in the location bar in your internet browser. The root node is actually a distrubuted network of nameservers, spread across many countries, hosted by many organizations and companies.

Going back to your resolver, it will have `hints` of where the root node name servers are. It will then go and ask one of root name servers as to which nameservers serve the `com` part of the DNS query. You can emulate this step with `host -t ns com` or `nslookup -q=ns com`. The nameserver will then use a forumla to pick one of the nameservers listed there and use it to ask for the `abx.com` domain.

At this point we reach a mechanism called delegation the `com` nameservers delegate the responsibility of `abx.com` to other nameservers, these are done by `NS` records. But those records contain domain *names* not IP addresses. The way these domains are affixed to one another is through `glue` records, so given abx.com as an example it would be something along the lines of:

```
 abx   IN    NS   ns1.abx.com
       IN    NS   ns2.abx.com
 ns1.abx.com IN A 10.10.10.10
 ns2.abx.com IN A 10.11.11.11
```

Your resolver would be given these A records, as additional info, in its request for the `NS` records of `abx.com` from the `com` nameservers. Your resolver then asks ns1.abx.com or ns2.abx.com for the `A` record for `abx.com`, and this returns the IP that in turn passes to the browser/process requesting that DNS record.

It's normally this last stage of delegation that is broken with most home user setups. They have gone through the process of buying a domain with a registrar/service provider, but have then failed to configure the domain to point the delegation to their own name servers. You actually have to tell the registrar where your nameservers are before they can put glue records in place to get your step of the delegation to work.

One that step has been done, the last part of the `recursion` used by the resolver slots into place. This is all provided that your abx.com zone is configured correctly, is being served to the internet at large and is not firewalled by either you or your hosting provider.

There are a plethora of DNS tool websites on the internet that will allow you to see what state your domain is in. (Such as [DNS Stuff's DNS tools](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools)). I also suggest you familiarize yourself with the `dig` tool which will allow you to specifically query specific name servers (and records) and get more detailed responses in the output.

**TLDR** Check your configuration with the hosting provider and make sure you have pointed the domains NS records at your nameservers IPs. Make sure you have no firewall blocking connections, your BIND is running and it is serving the correct DNS. Check the external DNS with external tools to check the state of your DNS.

Comment: I've answered your serverfault migrated question on delegtion as well Nishan: http://serverfault.com/questions/530415/what-is-dns-delegation/530518

Answer (score 5):

When people ask this I always tell them:

## Let somebody else host your DNS

Seriously. You don't have the network stability that professionals have and for DNS stability is key to a happy life. It's not weakness to admit that somebody else is better at it than you can be. They have something you don't: epic redundancy.

Most registrars offer a free load-balanced and redundant nameserver service, split over multiple servers in multiple locations. Same goes for web hosts and there are even free services out there that are pretty decent.

Comment: thank you for your advice.
but where did they get such features from. Over a period of time a long struggle and honesty of conduct was all that made them grow into giants as you see them now, but one day they were as little as an ant, which am i today. tomorrow can transform me into a learned man. **_SO AM I ASKING_**. I KNOW THAT THERE EVEN STARS THERE, BUT JUST BECAUSE THERE ARE STARS I CAN NOT STOP MY FEET ... _need i ???_

Comment: I've hosted my own DNS for years and never had any major issues (provided you have a minimum of two DNS servers, on two different networks with fairly guaranteed network connectivity and uptime, that is all that is required).

Comment: @Nishan By that logic, break out the soldering gun and let's build a server from scratch.

Comment: @Nishan If you want to experiment with DNS, do it first for an internal network. ＠Oli Why stop at assembling parts? [Make your own chips](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/how-are-integrated-circuits-fabricated/67604#67604)! Or is using existing silicon unacceptable? [Make your own universe](http://physics.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: @Oli, with due respect I would say even the **Debian** is not build that way...
We all have our levels and we all start from that level and with the good help we achieve one level up and finally the top becomes smaller before us.
**Information is for development not scaring someone**
Than you.

Comment: @Gilles, yes of course **MAKE YOUR OWN UNIVERSE** ... Thank you very much  for quoting these golden words.

Answer (score 1):

Go register a domain name for your site which will be visible to the world. Register for DNS (Domain Naming Service). The registrar will bind your IP address to the site name; this service will be paid.

Comment: This question had an accepted answer over 2 years ago.  Your answer does not answer the question or even add anything useful - the OP already had their own domain.